# Playing system sounds using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, system-sounds

I'm trying to play a sound when a button is pressed using system sounds. I keep getting the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I tried debugging, and I believe the error is occurring on the **var ref** line. "roar.aif" is a custom sound I have included in my project. It is only a second and a half long. I would appreciate suggestions. Thanks!

```
        var soundID: SystemSoundID = SystemSoundID()
        var mainBundle: CFBundleRef = CFBundleGetMainBundle()
        var ref: CFURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, "roar.aif", nil, nil) as CFURLRef!
        println("Here is your ref: \(ref)")
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, &soundID)
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct way is to use the filetype in the third parameter:

```
    var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
    var mainBundle: CFBundleRef = CFBundleGetMainBundle()
    if let ref: CFURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("roar"), CFSTR("aif"), nil) {
        println("Here is your ref: \(ref)")
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, &soundID)
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
    } else {
        println("Could not find sound file")
    }
```

Are you sure the file is roar.aif and not roar.aiff?

Make sure the file is not in a subdirectory, if so you have to add this as a fourth parameter.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBundleCopyResourceURL

Comment: This worked...sort of. It printed that it could not find the sound file, although my sound file is visible in my project navigator as roar.aif...Any thoughts?

Comment: Check the 'Build Phases' of your target. In the 'Copy Bundle Resources' section this file roar.aif should be present.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much! You've been a huge help!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Tom's answer (which is totally right), here is a slightly more robust error handler (which will help quell Apple's app testers)

```
else {
        let networkIssueController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Unable to find an audio file!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        networkIssueController.addAction(okButton)

        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        networkIssueController.addAction(cancelButton)

        self.presentViewController(networkIssueController, animated: true, completion: nil)// you have to display the alert after you create it
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.0**

```
func createSystemSoundID() -> SystemSoundID {
    var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
    let soundURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), "roar", "aiff", nil)
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &soundID)
    return soundID
}
```

Create it once:

```
let systemSoundID = createSystemSoundID()
```

Invoke at will:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.1**

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "roar", ofType: "aif") {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) as CFURL
    var soundID: SystemSoundID = 0
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url, &soundID)
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
} else {
    print("file not found!")
}
```